# SelectionInput forms using Google Cards RPC API

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building a Workspace add-on using the JSON Card API (i.e. *not* via Apps Script. I couldn't find a SO tag for this): https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/reference/rpc/google.apps.card.v1 .

Forms elements are declared with the SelectionInput object :

https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/reference/rpc/google.apps.card.v1?hl=en#selectioninput

I want the form to be sent only by clicking on a "Send" button.

How is form submission handled when `onChangeAction` is *not* specified ?  I see "If specified, the form is submitted when the selection changes. If not specified, you must specify a separate button.", but what if the Card has more than one button ? The documentation and the API don't seem to account for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be : all button clicks implicitly send all form data inside the `commonEventObject.formInputs` field of the JSON request body.

For instance, if we have a form named `form_test` with radio buttons having values 1, 2, 3 and select the first one, `formInputs` will be :

```
{"form_test":{"stringInputs":{"value":["1"]}}}
```

Thank you Google for not documenting the semantics of your APIs!